# NSWindow fixed position while switching between Spaces (Desktops)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow, appkit

Is it possible to fix position of `NSWindow` while switching between spaces?

It is possible to use `window?.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces]` to share window in all spaces, but I want same effect like `Dock` or `Picture in Picture` does - the NSWindow always stays in same position, even if we switch spaces.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the window level?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I can't seem to find anything regarding this topic.